# measure induced by a monotone continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

let $F$ be a continuous monotone increasing function on real line.if $A$ is an interval with endpoint $a,b$ we define:
$\mu _F (A)=F(b)-F(a)$

and if $A$ is a disjoint union of intervals,

$A=\cup_{1}^n A_i$

$\mu _F (A)=\Sigma _{i=1}^n \mu _F (A_i)$

prove that $\mu_F$ is countably additive.

this is what i've done:

$F$ maps the intervals to intervals , so $\mu _F (A)=\mu_LF(A)$ when $\mu_L$ is lebesgue measure on real line.

and we have:

$\Sigma _{i=1}^n \mu _F (A_i)=\mu_F(\cup_{1}^n A_i)=\mu_L(F(\cup_{1}^n A_i))$

and if a tend $N$ to infinity, i get:

$\Sigma _{i=1}^\infty \mu _F (A_i)=\mu_L(F(\cup_{1}^\infty A_i))$

but how to say these equal $\mu_F(\cup_{1}^\infty A_i)$?

thanks.

Comment: Hint: how would you ${\it define}$ the $\mu_F$-measure of $\cup_1^{\infty}A_i$?

Comment: @uniquesolution it must be $ \mu_L F(\cup A_i)$

Comment: @uniquesolution i think i've solved it almostly.but i feel confused.

Comment: Suppose you didn't have the Lebesgue measure. How would then define the $\mu_F$ measure of a countable union, based only on the definition you are given (without reference to any other measure).

Comment: @uniquesolution sorry i can't understand u.